# How to assign vals to a Eigen Block of dynamic matrix

Tags: c++11, ros, eigen3

I'd like to save vals of point cloud of `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` in a `Eigen::Block` of dynamic matrix which I rename its name as View

```
typedef typename Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Matrix;
typedef Eigen::Block<Matrix> View;
```

Then, in the source code, I declare a View object with the block of another atrix using `()` constructor:

```
View view(
(it->name == "normal_x") ? cloud.getDescriptorRowViewByName("normals", 0) : 
((it->name == "normal_y") ? cloud.getDescriptorRowViewByName("normals", 1): 
((it->name == "normal_z") ? cloud.getDescriptorRowViewByName("normals", 2): 
((isFeature[fieldId]) ? cloud.getFeatureViewByName(it->name) :
cloud.getDescriptorViewByName(it->name))))
         );
```

where `getFeatureViewByName()` is a function returning matrix block.

```
template<typename T>
typename PointMatcher<T>::DataPoints::View PointMatcher<T>::DataPoints::getFeatureViewByName(const std::string& name)
{
    return getViewByName(name, featureLabels, features);
}

template<typename T>
typename PointMatcher<T>::DataPoints::View PointMatcher<T>::DataPoints::getDescriptorRowViewByName(const std::string& name, const unsigned row)
{
    return getViewByName(name, descriptorLabels, descriptors, int(row));
}

template<typename T>
template<typename MatrixType>
typename Eigen::Block<MatrixType> PointMatcher<T>::DataPoints::getViewByName(const std::string& name, const Labels& labels, MatrixType& data, const int viewRow) const
{
    unsigned row(0);
    for(BOOST_AUTO(it, labels.begin()); it != labels.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->text == name)
        {
            if (viewRow >= 0)
            {
                if (viewRow >= int(it->span))
                    throw InvalidField(
                        (boost::format("Requesting row %1% of field %2% that only has %3% rows") % viewRow % name % it->span).str()
                    );
                return data.block(row + viewRow, 0, 1, data.cols());
            }
            else
                return data.block(row, 0, it->span, data.cols());
        }
        row += it->span;
    }
    throw InvalidField("Field " + name + " not found");
}
```

But when I try reassigning vals to it, the segment fault occurred:
`view(0, ptId) = T(*reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(fPtr));`
where `ptId` is a `int` number and iterate from 0.

I can successfully `cout` the vals of `*reinterpret_cast<const float*>(fPtr)` which means the accessing of the array is valid. I also found if I use `cloud.getFeatureViewByName(it->name).setConstant(1);` to assign vals to the matrix, it is valid, but if `cout` the matrix after assignment, it is invalid. It's so weird!

As far as I know, if the declaration of a dynamic matrix with known size or other fixed-size matrix, the assignment and accessing of the matrix should be legal. Is this the problem of the version of Eigen?

Comment: Makes sure that `getDescriptorRowViewByName` and `getFeatureViewByName` does not return references to temporaries, even implicitly. In doubt, include them in your question. Also, if the return types of them is not exactly `View` then better define `View` as a `Eigen::Ref<Matrix>`.

Comment: Are you sure it is caused by the `Block` and not by accessing `fPtr` (just assign `view(0,ptId) = T(0);` to check that. Also, try to provide a [mre], ideally with as little dependencies as possible (if you think the error is on how you use Eigen, you should be able to provide an example which does not depend on ROS)

Comment: This is still not a [mre] -- read that link how and why to provide that.